# For loop with increasing setTimeout interval

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get a for loop to run 3 times with an increasing interval each time. I'd like the loop to output text to the console each time it runs but I can't stop the loop from running all at once and showing done, finished, and done, then finished twice. Code:

```
function tellMeWhenDone () {

  for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
          if (i === 0)
                  var text = console.log('done');

          else if (i === 1)
                  var text = console.log('and done');

          else (i === 2)
                  var text = console.log('finished');

          time(i);
}
}

     function time (i){
             setInterval(function(text){
        return text;
      }, 1000*(i+1))
}
tellMeWhenDone();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: why  "else (i === 2)" has condition ??

Comment: Else has a condition because I'm inexperienced with JS. I accept that using 3 separate setTimeout statements with 1000, 2000, and 3000ms intervals will get me the result I'm looking for. I'm trying to construct this function as an exercise, so that's why I may not be going about this in the most direct way. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Why `var text = console.log('done');`? What value do you expect for *text* and what will you do with it? Why *if..else* when you can do `['done','and done','finished'][i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setInterval** sets up a recurring event. **setTimeout** will only fire once.

To create three timeouts, 1, 2 and 3 seconds - you may use:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log('done')},1000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log('and done')},2000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log('finished')},3000);
```

Notice there is no loop.  Each setTimeout executes and when the timeout is reached, the console.log statement is run.

Your for loop is executing completely before the setInterval call.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the condition in else loop

```js
function tellMeWhenDone() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i === 0)
      var text = console.log('done');

    else if (i === 1)
      var text = console.log('and done');

    else
      var text = console.log('finished');

    time(i);
  }
}

function time(i) {
  setInterval(function(text) {
    return text;
  }, 1000 * (i + 1))
}
tellMeWhenDone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..I hope its resolved your prblm

```
 function tellMeWhenDone () {

 for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
      if (i === 0)
              var text = console.log('done');

      else if (i === 1)
              var text = console.log('and done');

      else if (i === 2)
              var text = console.log('finished');

      time(i);
}
}

 function time (i){
         setInterval(function(text){
    return text;
  }, 1000*(i+1))
}
 tellMeWhenDone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with callback:

```js
function log(msg) {
  document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML += '<br/>' + msg;
}

function on_complete() {
  log('all done, when = ' + Date.now());
}

for (var i = 1, max = 5; max >= i; i++) {
  (function(x) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      log('loop, x = ' + x + ', when = ' + Date.now());
      if (max === x)
        on_complete();
    }, 1000 * x); //increasing timeout
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<pre id='logger'>Running code...</pre>
```